# Is Stack Overflow a suitable place for a WordPress question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I know this is an odd question, but is Stack Overflow (the main site) the right place to ask a question about WordPress? I ask this because I have rarely seen any and have spent quite a bit of time looking for an answer to a question that I have.

I need to find the answer, but I am afraid I cannot, if anyone could say "yes or no" to asking a question about WordPress on S/O that would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I'm not sure why you rolled back many of the edits to your question. The 'help' tag is for questions about the Stack Exchange help functions, not that you need help, so is inappropriate for your question. Also, emoticons and "thank you" are unnecessary noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to go to [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). It is the best site for you to ask questions about the development of a WordPress site. Of course, SO is also fine, but I think asking a question on a site more suitable to your topic of question is better.

Comment: Thank you!! Absolute legend!